# How to align a custom list using enumerate

Tags: align, enumerate

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{9in}
\setlength{\headheight}{20pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{20pt}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.25in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6in}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color,graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mhequ}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\newlist{steps}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[steps, 1]{start = 0, label = Step \arabic*:}

Here is the beginning of my paragraph. Here is the beginning of my paragraph.Here is the beginning of my paragraph.Here is the beginning of my paragraph.Here is the beginning of my paragraph.

\begin{steps}
\item 
\item
\end{steps}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I defined a custom list using `enumerate`. However, the `Step 0, 1, ...` are not aligned with the other paragraphs in the document. How can I indent this custom list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the `wide` and `widest` options.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{9in}
\setlength{\headheight}{20pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{20pt}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.25in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6in}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color,graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mhequ}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\newlist{steps}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[steps, 1]{start = 0, label = Step \arabic*:,wide=3pt, widest=step 00:}

Here is the beginning of my paragraph. Here is the beginning of my paragraph. Here is the beginning of my paragraph.Here is the beginning of my paragraph.Here is the beginning of my paragraph.

\begin{steps}
\item 
\item
\end{steps}
\end{document}
```

[image]